# Get value form a read-only text box

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, textbox, readonly

I have a `Textbox` that is set to `read-only` on load on some condition.
I need to assign the value in that `Textbox` to a `session` object,
I'm getting the below error:

> System.NotSupportedException: Collection is
>   read-only.

below is my code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtKSPRNumber" runat="server" 
             CssClass="form-control" ReadOnly="true">
</asp:TextBox>
```

i need to get the text inside the above `TextBox` and set it into a `Session` object as below :

```
Session["KSPRNumberForPO"] = txtKSPRNumber.Text;
```

Any suggestion please.

Comment: I have the feeling that it has nothing to do with the textbox. Can you post the line that throws this exception

Comment: what is the "session" that you try to assign the value to?

Comment: Show us your code to solve your problem

Comment: i just added the code above

Comment: @MarwahAbdelaal did you set the session state to read only?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) says the following:

> You can disable session state for an application by setting the session-state mode to Off. If you want to disable session state for only a particular page of an application, you can set the EnableSessionState value in the @ Page directive to false. The EnableSessionState value can also be set to ReadOnly to provide read-only access to session variables.

Might it be that you actually set the session state to read only?

Please have a look at the [EnableSessionState Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.enablesessionstate.aspx). It is probably responsible for you error

Answer (score 0):

When you set the `Textbox` value , you must set the `ReadOnly` property to `false`. And then set it to `true` again.

Answer (score 0):

You can set values (i.e. Text) in read-only textbox. Please show the code.

Below code is working fine on Page Load

```
txtKSPRNumber.Text = "sampleSession";

Session["KSPRNumberForPO"] = txtKSPRNumber.Text;
```

Comment: **System.NotSupportedException: Collection is read-only.**

TextBox is not a collection. This means, issue is something different